# Using Notion API, I get "not found" errors trying to read any page

Tags: notion-api

I have generated a Notion API token for an "internal integration."
Using this API token, I can make authorized requests.
I've granted all the possible permissions to this token in the integrations management page.
However, I just can't read any pages. I try:

`curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer secret_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' -H 'Notion- Version: 2022-06-27' https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/FFFFFFFFFFFFF`

And I get this error:

`{"object":"error","status":404,"code":"object_not_found","message":"Could not find page with ID: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF. Make sure the relevant pages and databases are shared with your integration."}`

It also doesn't work trying `/v1/blocks/FFFFFFF/children` with a similar not-found error.

I copy the ID from the end of a Notion URL:

`https://www.notion.so/mycompany/Some-page-title-FFFFFFFFFFF`

The permission are "open to all in the organization" and "open to all in the workspace."

Soooo ... what am I missing?

The error message and documentation suggest I should be able to "invite" the integration to a page. However, the integration does not come up as a match when typing in the "Invite" search box for the page.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that the documentation and error messages are all old.
These days, you have to "Add Connection ..." in the three-dot menu, rather than "Invite" the integration.
After I do this, it works.